# How do I get the value of the selected customer to echo <input> element?

Tags: php, mysql

Database info:

```
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS tz_customer (
    id INT (10) NOT NULL,
    customervarchar (255) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    vs_1 VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    stamp VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
)
```

And PHP Code

THIS IS index.php FILE

`<select name="nimetus" id="nimetus" onchange="chg(this.value)">`
`<?php $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tz_kliendid"); while ($f3 = mysql_fetch_array($q3)) { ?>` 
`<option value="<?php echo $f3['id']; ?>"><?php echo $f3['klient']; ?></option><?php } ?></select>`

`<input type="text" id="target" value="">`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">function chg(str){
  $.ajax({
            url: "showdata.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "val": str
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#target").val(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("Some error found!!");
            }
        });
}</script>`

AND showdata.php FILE

`<?php if(isset($_GET['val'])){$nimetus=$_POST['nimetus'];
        $q1=mysql_query("SELECT vs_1 FROM tz_kliendid WHERE id='".$nimetus."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); $f1=mysql_fetch_array($q1); echo $f1['vs_1']; } ?>`

Each customer has a "tz customer" table "vs_1" column marked 0 or 1.
When I choose a customer, how can I reach the selected customer "vs_1" value from the table?

And

How do I get the value of the selected customer to echo `<input>` element?

Comment: So cryptic.. `vs_1` is another table? If so you could create a `JOIN` between the two table to select all the data you need from the other table as well

Comment: "vs_1" is located in the same table, ie "tz_customer"

Comment: You want the customer that is flagged with `vs_1 == 1` to be selected in the dropdown by default?

Comment: if I choose the customer on select option, echo out selected customer vs_1 value without submit using

Comment: @MarioLaul Kindly stop using mysql_ it's been deprecated start using mysqli_ or PDO now because PHP5.5 is going to end soon.

Comment: soon or not but my service provider is using the old version and said that will not change, since it has nearly 300 customers, who are using all the old versions of MySQL

Comment: You need to change you service provider than

Comment: when it comes time to deal with it right then, but at the moment I want to deal with this issue, which worries me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I don't completely understand your question as far as i can understand you need vs_1 value of every customer when you change that select.You need to change your option value as id as it is the primary.You need ajax to do this

```
<select name="nimetus" id="nimetus" onchange="chg(this.value)">
<?php
  while ($f3 = mysql_fetch_array($q3)) {
   ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $f3['id'];  ?>">
      <?php echo $f3['customer'];  ?>
  </option>
   <?php
}
?> 
</select>
<input type="text" id="target" value="">
```

In java script

```
function chg(str){
  $.ajax({
            url: "showdata.php",
            type: "POST", //send it through post method
            data: {
                "val": str
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //Do Something
                $("#target").val(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                //Do Something to handle error
                alert("Some error found!!");
            }
        });
}
```

In showdata.php

```
if(isset($_POST['val']))//your POST method
  {
    $nimetus=$_POST['val'];
    $q1=mysql_query("SELECT vs_1 FROM tz_kliendid WHERE id='".$nimetus."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
   $f1=mysql_fetch_array($q1); 
   echo $f1['vs_1'];
  }
```

Comment: that's correct and you understand my question, but how can i get vs_1 value without submit?

Comment: What do you mean without submit?
I do not understand your question as well but i think you want the values before submit in your select options so you should try ajax and get values from db and set the options

Comment: if I choose the customer on select option, echo out selected customer vs_1 value without submit using

Comment: you want to use ajax for that

Comment: I changed the answer please check

Comment: maybe something wrong, but not working. i put showdata.php //mysql_process// task next $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

Comment: $row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql)); and don't forget to add jquery library

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i change my question, please look that. Maybe something wrong. Don't work

Comment: sorry i forgot to change if(isset($_GET['val'])) to if(isset($_POST['val']))

Comment: use showdata.php in my answer i edited the file and tested in localhost it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data-attribute to hold the value of `v1` and then access it with jquery to display it, by doing this you won't need to have an extra ajax call each time you change the value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $option = '';
            $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tz_customer");
            while ($f3 = mysql_fetch_array($q3)) {
                $option .= '
                    <option value="' . $f3['customer'] . '"' . ($f3['id'] == $f3['customer'] ? " selected" : "") . ' data-v1="'.$f3['v1'].'">
                        ' . $f3['customer'] . 
                    '</option>';
            } ?>
        <select name="nimetus" id="nimetus">
            <?= $option ?>
        </select>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#cbo').on('change', function() {
                var opt = $('option:selected', $(this));
                $('#output').html(opt.text()+ ' => v1 :'+ opt.data('v1'));
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```